# Como puedo editar un pdf?

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que necesito es una forma en la que pueda editar un PDF que ya esta establecido que se pueda  editar la informacion que ya esta en el pero sin necesidad que se guarde en base de datos si no que una vez editado se pueda guardar en cualquier parte de la computadora como pdf igual pero ya editado e investigado y no encuentro una forma de iniciar solo con la libreria ITextSharp

de antemano agradezco sus comentarios

Comment: la verdad desconozco si, para empezar eso es posible. lo que se me ocurriría para "editar" un PDF, seria re hacerlo con los cambios mencionados, no sé si te sirva de algo

Comment: si e investigado y no encuentro una forma en la que pueda seleccionar el pdf es un archivo que me envian y tengo que cambiarle las fechas y eso pero con las herramientas que ya hay me pierde calidad el archivo una vez lo vuelvo a convertir a pdf

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es convertir el pdf a html y de ahí mostrarlo en el navegador, ya acá podrás agregar más elementos con javascript y cuando esté listo , conviertes ese html a pdf